# abnormal TCP behaviour; sending and receiving data are different

Tags: java, tcp

I am implementing Distance Vector Protocol on a distributed network using JAVA. I am storing all nodes hops values in a HashTable and passing it to neighbor nodes. I am checking number of keys present in my HashTable and then passing it via MessageSender(self written class) and after receiving this HashTable at the neighbor end, I am again checking number of keys present and it is coming out 1 key short. It is happening in specific cases not in all cases which are predictable. Could you please suggest me what could be the issue here?
I tried ArrayList datastructure also in place of HashTable.

sending block is:

```
synchronized(TCPServer.node_list)
{
    msg.nodesDetails = TCPServer.node_list;
}
System.out.println("node_list.size "+msg.nodesDetails.size());
synchronized(sender_list)
{
    System.out.println("sending node_list contains");
    Enumeration<Integer> enumKey = msg.nodesDetails.keys();
    while(enumKey.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Integer key = enumKey.nextElement();                
        System.out.print(msg.nodesDetails.get(key).nodeNo+","+msg.nodesDetails.get(key).hops+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i=0  ; i<sender_list.size(); i++)
    {
        try
        {
            sender_list.get(i).ooss.writeObject(msg);
            System.out.println("Sending TCP msg to "+
                                  sender_list.get(i).receiverNodeNo + " node");
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Send message failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and receiving block is:

```
public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        try
        {
            Message msg = (Message)ois.readObject();
            System.out.println("Message received from node "+msg.senderId);
            Hashtable<Integer, Node> aai = msg.nodesDetails;
            int flag = 0;
            System.out.println("msg.nodesDetails.size "+msg.nodesDetails.size()+" of node "+msg.senderId);
```

Comment: You are using `ObjectOutputStream`.  Are you aware of the fact that it maintains a cache of objects that have already been written, so that if you write an object, modify it, and write it again, the receiver gets the unmodified object twice? There's not enough information to tell if this can be the problem.

Comment: That's a great help. Now I am resetting the ObjectOutputStream before sending new data and its working perfectly fine. :)
Thank you very much.